# how to password protect any field in form (wants suggestions)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Here I want to create one field(select box- dropdown) in form which is password protected.

when user click on that dropwon one prompt appears, over here user enter the password , and if password is correct then and after then user can select value of that dropdown box.

so how i can achieve this functionality?

Comment: disable the dropdown until the password is correct, then enable it again.

Comment: Well i am guessing that you already determine if a user has access to that field or not. Why not just dont give the option of selecting the field if if the current_user does not have access

Comment: What is the question? SO is not a code writing service, please provide evidence of your work so far

Comment: you can use a client-side cipher to hide the values inside the <option>s, de-ciphering them to the password provided by the user. this lets you avoid server interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

- disable/hide the `select`
- `onclick`: open a `prompt` or `dialog`
- `onsubmit`: send the data via **AJAX** and check the password in background with PHP (or another **server-side** language)
- enable/show the `select`, if the password was right

Notice:

- Javascript is readable by the client, you've to check the password with PHP (or another server-side language). If you write the password in Javascript, the user could figure it out by reading the source code.
- The user could manipulate the HTML and Javascript local. You must verify all of his sent data on the server side.

By the way

- I would enable/disable the select due to the users rights

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no pre-made solution for you - you will have to develop your own, i.e. display disabled dropdown initially, display your own password form pop-up on click event, compare if passwords match and if they do, finally enable the dropdown.

The most challenging issue here will be password protection. If you want to have this feature at least a little secure, you can't just include correct password in your js/jquery source code. Either use encryption or AJAX for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could position a invisible div over the field absolutely, and listen for a click event on that div. If the password is correct remove the div. 
If you wanted to be security conscience I wouldn't include the dropdown at all unless they get the password right. Return the contents of the select once the password is correct.
Once the password is correct you can populate the selectfield and open it.

Because even if you disable the select like others are saying there is nothing stopping someone from going into the html and enabling it. It needs to be unavailable unless verified.